# cgi python3 problems with encoding

Tags: python-3.x, character-encoding, cgi

I created a cgi script (running at localhost with apache) which will load text from textarea and then I will work with it. I have problems with characters like š,ť,é,.. that they are not displayed correctly. I tried it in many ways. Here is one version of my shortcode in which I am just searching for the right way to deal with it.

```
#!C:/Python33/python 
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
 
import cgi
import cgitb

cgitb.enable()

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
if form.getvalue('textcontent'):
   text_content = form.getvalue('textcontent')
else:
   text_content = ""


print ("Content-type:text/html")
print ()
print("<!DOCTYPE html>")
print ("<html>")
print ("<head>")
print("<meta charset='UTF-8'></meta>")
print ("</head>")
print ("<body>")
print ("<form>")
print ("text_area:<br />")
print ("<textarea name='textcontent' rows='5' cols='20'></textarea>")
print ("<br />")
print ("<input type='submit' value='submit form' />")
print ("</form>")
print("<p>")
print(text_content) 
print("</p>")
print ("</body>")
print ("</html>")
```

This way is using UTF-8, when I try to write something, it looks like this (write to textarea and submit):

```
čítam -> ��tam
```

When I use latin-1 as python encoding and utf-8 as charset in html part it works like this:

```
časa -> časa (correctly)
```

but with characters with an accent mark (for example áno) it returns error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\\ufffd' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>\r
```

With `sys.stdout.encoding` it writes `cp1250` encoding (work under windows) and with `sys.getdefaultencoding()` it returns `utf-8`

I tried also `text_content = (form.getvalue('textcontent')).encode('utf-8')` for example word `číslo` and result is `b'\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbdslo'`

I don't know how to handle this problem.

I need `číslo -> číslo` fo example.

UPDATE: Now I have UTF-8 for python as html encoding. It looks like work with text (comparing words with the dictionary,..) is going well, so the only one problem now is that output looks like ��tam, so I need to modify it to look like čítam instead of ��tam.

UPDATE 2: When encoding is UTF-8, and in browser UTF-8 too, it displays �s, when I change browser encoding to cp1250, it displays correctly, but when I refresh the site or click on Submit button it writes error  `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\\ufffd'`

UPDATE 3: Tried it on linux and after a few problems I found out that apache server is using wrong encoding(ascii), but I can't accomplish this problem yet. Modified  `/etc/apache2/envvars` to PATH LANG="sk_SK.UTF-8" but got some warning in the terminal by gedit that editing was not good. So encoding is still ascii.

Answer (score 1):

write your form in this way:

```
<form accept-charset="utf-8">
```

put `accept-charset = "utf-8"` in your forms, it can solve this problems